# Rails/Heroku precompiled assets not being found

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, heroku, assets

I'm pretty new to Rails and Heroku, and I'm trying to deploy an app which uses the jQuery UI library. I have the jQuery UI Javascript and CSS files in my `app/assets` folder, and I have it set to precompile assets (I had to do that to get my app actually running on Heroku). However, the jQuery UI files are not being found when I load the page (jQuery UI is not working). From what I've gathered, it renames the files to `<filename>-<md5 hash>.js/css`. How can I make it reference the right file?

`app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400,300" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Comment: Could you show the code where the jQuery UI file is included?

Comment: Edited the post to include it

Answer (score 5):

I actually would recommend removing the precompiled assets function and allowing Heroku to do this for you.  I initially started off like you did, however quickly found that it was a superior approach and recommended by Heroku support to do the asset compilation during slug compilation.

Be sure that you're using the Cedar stack rather than Bamboo and [take a look at this](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar) and then follow below to the troubleshooting section:
[image]

The side note is especially important: "If a `public/assets/manifest.yml` is detected in your app, Heroku will assume you are handling asset compilation yourself and will not attempt to compile your assets."

Be sure that you remove everything under your public/assets/* folder that the precompile has created, including that `manifest.yml` file.

Otherwise all of your JavaScript files in `app/assets/javascripts` should automatically be included and you should be able to see so while checking in your dev mode (in production mode on heroku by default they'll be all minified into one application.js file, but if they show up in dev mode, you should be gold).

Comment: you can clean out your public/assets folder with: `bundle exec rake assets:clean`.  Then commit and push, and you should be right.

Comment: When you deploy, check the output for `Detected manifest.yml, assuming assets were compiled locally` For me, I had accidentally committed my assets once and while I had deleted the files locally, I forget the `git rm public/assets/*` so there was still a manifest.yml file on the heroku server.

Comment: I have no manifest.yml file, no a public/assets folder. When I do git push to heroku, it does not compile my application.css or .js files. I have it in my application.rb written : `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` `config.assets.precompile << 'application.css'`, etc.. still nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on the default Bamboo stack, you will need to precompile the assets by `rake assets:precompile` yourself and commit the results in public/assets and push them to Heroku. Otherwise, using the [Cedar](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar) stack might be an easier choice.

Answer (score 0):

As described here (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#static-assets) you
should add the 'rails_serve_static_assets' gem to your Gemfile, and the problem will be fixed.