# Rails Isotope Javascript assets not found on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, jquery-isotope

I'm having a problem with two Javascript files used by Isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) in my /app/assets folder not being found on Heroku. In development mode locally, they are found and everything works fine. However once in production mode on Heroku, the two files aren't there. I've read a lot of similar posts on Stack Overflow and read a lot about the asset pipeline, but I still can't seem to figure out what's causing the problem.

Here's what I know:

1) Other Javascript files in my /app/assets folder are being found, including Bootstrap.

2) If I do rake assets:precompile -trace, I don't get any errors and everything seems normal.

3) In my production.rb file, config.serve_static_assets = true. A lot of people seemed to switch this from false to true and it fixed their issue, but at this point I'm not sure which it should be.

4) This issue might be due to the Isotope Javascript files in question. In one of my html.erb files, I have added some Javascript to do with Isotope as per the developer's docs, like this:

```
 <script src="../assets/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function(){

      var $container = $('#eventcontainer');
      $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container.isotope({
          layoutMode : 'spineAlign',
          spineAlign: {
              gutterWidth: 30
          },
          itemSelector : '.element',

      });
     });
 ....... more here that works in dev mode...
  </script>
```

I think the problem results from these two lines:

```
<script src="../assets/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
```

Since if I remove them, my app can't find the Javascript files even when running in development. However, they are included in my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery-1.7.1.min
//= require jquery.isotope.min
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require bootstrap-timepicker
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
```

so I'm not sure why they aren't being found or how to fix the problem. I'm fairly new to Rails and especially to Heroku, so I would really appreciate any help. If you need more info or to see any other files, please let me know.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by removing the lines

```
<script src="../assets/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
```

and using info found here: [Rails/Heroku precompiled assets not being found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935214/rails-heroku-precompiled-assets-not-being-found?rq=1). Specifically, the following:

> The side note is especially important: "If a
>   public/assets/manifest.yml is detected in your app, Heroku will assume
>   you are handling asset compilation yourself and will not attempt to
>   compile your assets."
>
> Be sure that you remove everything under your public/assets/* folder
>   that the precompile has created, including that manifest.yml file.

After removing everything in public/assets/* by doing a bundle exec rake assets:clean, I then pushed to Heroku again, allowing it to compile assets itself. At that point it worked. I'm not entirely sure the reasoning, maybe someone could explain it, but to me it seems like once those two  lines were removed and all the assets were recompiled, it knew to look in the correct location for the Isotope Javascript files.